# Number of even integers not satisfying Goldbach's conjecture from Vinogradov. Infinity of numbers not satisfying the Goldbach's conjecture.

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

> If $A(x)$ is the number of even integers less than $x$ that don't write as a sum of two (odd) primes, then $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{A(x)}{x} = 0$$

That is what is written in my book (*Elementary Number Theory* from Burton) in the chapter dedicated to the Goldbach conjecture. It is a result from Vinogradov.

It then says that "almost all" even integers satisfy the conjecture.

---

I don't understand. If $A(x)\sim _{\infty} \sqrt{x}$ (for example) then the Vinogradov relation would be satisfied and yet there'd be plenty of integers **not** satisfying the conjecture. Is my example in accordance with the affirmation that "almost all" even integers satisfy the conjecture? If $A(x)\sim _{\infty} \sqrt{x}$ were true, how would "almost all" integers satisfying the conjecture fit with the infinity (what I called "plenty") of integers not satisfying the conjecture?

EDIT: Here is what I understand so far:

Let $B(x)$ be the number of even integers less than $x$ that satisfy the Goldbach conjecture. We have that $B(x) = x/2 - A(x)$

Hence, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{B(x)}{x} = 1/2$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a sort of postscript to GEdgar's answer below, composite numbers, numbers that are not perfect squares, numbers that are not perfect (!), and numbers that are not $1$ are all "almost all" numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all#Meaning_in_number_theory)

> In number theory, "almost all positive integers" can mean "the positive integers in a set whose natural density is 1".